# Can't install Spatie Activity-log Package in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, activitylog

I was going to install spatie-activitylog package in my laravel application.

```
composer require spatie/laravel-activitylog
```

But I got this error.

```
 Problem 1
        - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - spatie/laravel-activitylog 3.14.0 requires illuminate/support ^6.0|^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[7.x-dev], illuminate/support[6.x-dev, 7.x-dev, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0
    .3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.2, v6.18.3, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6
    .5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.3.0]
    .
        - spatie/laravel-activitylog 3.14.1 requires illuminate/support ^6.0|^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[7.x-dev], illuminate/support[6.x-dev, 7.x-dev, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0
    .3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.2, v6.18.3, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6
    .5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.3.0]
    .
        - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[7.x-dev, v5.8.37].
        - don't install illuminate/support 6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - don't install illuminate/support 7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.10.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.11.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.12.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.13.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.13.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.14.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.15.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.15.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.16.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.17.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.17.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.4.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.5.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - don't install illuminate/support v6.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
        - don't install illuminat

e/support v6.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.1.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.2.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.2.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.8.37, required as 5.8.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.37].
    - Installation request for spatie/laravel-activitylog ^3.14 -> satisfiable by spatie/laravel-activitylog[3.14.0, 3.14.1].
```

This package doesn't support laravel 5.8 anymore?
I think Laravel 5.8 isn't so old.
Should I use Laravel 7.0 which is latest version?
Is there any version which supports laravel 5.8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed Spatie's activitylog doens't support Laravel 5.8 anymore.

That's what's specified in the [`composer.json`](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-activitylog/blob/master/composer.json):

```
"illuminate/config": "^6.0|^7.0",
"illuminate/database": "^6.0|^7.0",
"illuminate/support": "^6.0|^7.0"
```

I would advise you to upgrade to the latest version of Laravel. Many useful features were added.

Comment: Thank you
Then, which version of package support laravel 5.8?

Comment: In version [3.9.2](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-activitylog/releases/tag/3.9.2) they dropped support for Laravel 5. So everything before that release should still work with your application.

Comment: Great!. 3.9.1 worked for laravel 5. 8.
composer require spatie/laravel-activitylog:3.9.1

Answer (score 4):

Easily installed in my **Laravel 5.8.35**

```
composer require spatie/laravel-activitylog "^3.9.1"
```

You can always check the **requires** section (compatibility) of any package at [Packagist](https://packagist.org/) with your Laravel/PHP version etc.